# How do I unregister an Archetypes schema extender?

Tags: python, plone, zope

I'm trying to uninstall `collective.carousel`'s archetypes schemaextender (I'm only interessed in the portlet from that package, not adding Carousel source to every `PloneFormGen` field etc).

I've tried to unregister the adapter using a import-step, but have so far failed.

```
def unregister_carousel_extender(site):
    from collective.carousel.schemaextender import ContentTypeExtender
    from archetypes.schemaextender.interfaces import ISchemaExtender
    from Products.ATContentType.interfaces import IATContentType

    sm = site.getSiteManager()
    sm.unregisterAdapter(factory=ContentTypeExtender, provided=(ISchemaExtender,), required=(IATContentType), name=u'')
```

I've also spent time in pdb without any success. I'm able to get hold of the registered adapters and can see that `collective.carousel.schemaextender.ContentTypeExtender` is registered as an unnamed adapter.

Answer (score 1):

You can't unregister on an import step. Import steps only run when you import the profile. In contrast zcml declarations will be parsed and executed when you start your instance. So make sure you unregister *after* the adapter has been registered, *every* time.

Answer (score 0):

The 'required' parameter needs to be a sequence of interfaces rather than a single interface. So, required=[IATContentType] or required=(IATContentType,) (note the comma!) rather than required=(IATContentType).

You can check the return value from unregisterAdapter to find out if it was successful...if it's False, it didn't find the adapter you specified (which usually means one of the parameters is incorrect).

Answer (score 0):

What you want is to undo some zcml of collective.carousel when Zope starts up.  You can do that with the [z3c.unconfigure](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/z3c.unconfigure) package.

(Note that I am not sure if the portlet of collective.carousel still works correctly when you have unconfigured this part of the zcml.)